# Como puedo hacer, que cuando se detecte ?view=panel se agrege &hola=quetal&var=ko

Tags: php

Hola como dice la pregunta me gustaria como puedo agregar &hola=quetal en el buscador.

aqui la linea del codigo:

```
$view = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : 'panel';
```

de aqui que puedo hacer?

Comment: Has probado algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
if (isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == “panel” && !isset($_GET[“hola”])) {
  header(“location: “ . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . “&hola=quetal”);
}
```

Lo que hace ese código (que debería ir al principio del todo para evitar problemas con la redirección) es comprobar que el parámetro view está ahí y tiene el valor panel. Y si eso ocurre, entonces se redirecciona a la misma url añadiendo el nuevo parámetro hola con valor quetal.

Comment: Aunque igual deberías plantearte hacerlo con .htaccess en lugar de desde PHP.

Comment: pero me lo repite cada rato

Comment: l&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&hola=quetal&h.......

Comment: @ChicoMinecraftVillanueva he actualizado la respuesta para solucionar ese problema. Perdón estoy en móvil y no probé esa posibilidad.

Comment: y si quiero agregar mas que solo&hola por ejemplo:

Comment: &hola=nsdjk&josu=poa&id=233

Comment: Podrías añadirlos al final del `header` detrás del hola=quetal.